# Merge facebook website page with facebook app page

Tags: api, facebook-page

I started this website last year, along with a facebook page.
http://www.facebook.com/textbookcentral

I just implemented some more facebook features into my website, which used an app's ID to authenticate with facebook servers.
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=214000968642435

Is there a way I can merge both? When users click on the App link on the wall posts my App made, they get taken to the App page, which is empty.

Mainly, I want to keep the http://www.facebook.com/textbookcentral URL, and when people click on the App page, it would have the http://www.facebook.com/textbookcentral URL. It would be a bonus if I could import all the original facebook pages' content, too.

Or, make the App link on wall posts on users page to link to the original page instead.

Comment: Gosh, I'm guessing the -1 was for the api tag. Stackoverflow made me do it. I couldn't think of a more relevant "non facebook related tag", which stackoverflow forced me to add before allowing me to submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that as of Feb 1st Application Profile Pages are GONE !

[Removing App Profile Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611)

As for your questions, the link above contains the information about the migration process